# C# RAW Printing

Tags: c#, printing, postscript, printer-control-language

I have a requirement whereby I need to be able to send an image to a printer.
The problem I have is that the target printer (and type) is not necessarily know at the time of printing and we could be sending to a zebra/intermec label printer or a standard HP office jet.

One further complication is that we have hundreds of printers to manage.
I do not want to have to install hundreds or printers and have to manually install a new printer every time we add one to the network. We maintain a list of IP Addresses and ports.
I have been considering installing a default printer (zebra, intermec, officejet) for each of the printer types.

When printing (using PrintDocument) I can send a print to the default printer of that type but mark the output as "PrintToFile". I believe this would then give me the raw print data (PCL?).

My thought process is that I should then be able to simply send the raw data to the printer? Unfortunately this does not seem to work and the raw text is simply printed.

Can anybody offer some advice/help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to have to choose an intermediate format that's compatible with all of these different printer types.  PDF and XPS are the common choices.

Comment: Postscript printers look for %! to say the data is to be interpreted as postscript, otherwise most PS printers will just print text. HP/PCL uses control codes to perfrom advanced imaging, otherwise it just prints text. I don't know of any easy way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Raw files will not be sharper than the JPG files on printing, for me the best solution is to convert the RAW file in JPG